# One Website to be connected with Multiple EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiple-instances, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS, i am already having a godaddy VPS server, but my application is very slow when i hosted it in goDaddy VPS.

So i migrated to AWS, now my application works very fast, but some times the EC2 instance is getting failed and it automatically restarts after some times. since my application is basically an on-demand service app, these instance failure causes me to lose some conversations. So i heard about load balancing service from amazon, if one instance failed automatically turns the traffic to other instance.

I have used ubuntu 16.04 instance with vestaCP to host my application in AWS EC2. So is it possible to use the storage of my current-master EC2 instance with a new-alternative instance? so that same datas and database will be used by both the EC2 instances.

Might my question looks funny, but i need to know whether its possible or not? if possible any tutorials! if its not possible what kind of services need to use AWS load balancer to handle high traffic and instance failure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are migrating from a more conventional hosting to a cloud provider but you don't adopt a cloud architecture, you are missing out many of the benefits of the cloud.

In general, for a highly available, highly scalable web application, having shared data locally is an anti-pattern.

A modern web application would separate state (storage) from processing. Ideally your instance would hold only configuration and temporary data. For the database, assuming you are using a relational database, you would start a [RDS instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/). For the files, if they are mainly things like images and static content, you would probably use [The Simple Storage Service, S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Your EC2 instance would connect to the RDS database and S3. Since the data is not local to the instance anymore, you can easily have multiple instances all using the same storage.

Your EC2 instances could be configured [with autoscaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/), so AWS would automatically add or remove instances responding to the real traffic you are seeing.

If you have complex storage needs and S3 is not enough for the file layer (and for most applications S3 should suffice), you can take a look at the [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is achievable through `ELB` of `AWS`. But you have mention for separate requirement of `ec2 instance`, there is no need of such as `AWS ELB` manages all this for you.

Note: Always keep your database on another instance like 'AWS RDS' featuring data backup, rollback and if one instance fails then another instance have access to database. Same for files should be stored on 'AWS S3' then only you can achieve load balancing.

For more information.
[link](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing)